# attr vs attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, oop

In Ruby there are four different getter and setter methods for instance variables, `attr`, `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor`. The question is, is in Ruby `attr :dilithium`, the same as `attr_reader :dilithium`, and identical to `attr_accessor :dilithium` if an additional parameter true is passed? That is to say is

```
class Enterprise
  attr :dilithium, true
```

identical to

```
class Enterprise
  attr_accessor :dilithium
```

Are the two functions `attr` and `attr_accessor` more or less redundant?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One difference is that `attr_accessor` and friends are clearer, and the optional boolean argument to `attr` is now [deprecated](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-attr). Other than that, and the fact that `attr` has no documentation, there's no real difference.

Comment: `attr` does have documentation, at least in 2.3.0. It's just an alias of `attr_reader`. Although, the way the documentation is organised is pretty poor, so perhaps it could be improved to make things clearer.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby 1.8, `attr` can define only a single attribute, with an optional `true` to create a setter . In 1.9 it behaves like `attr_reader`:it allows for multiple attributes. As @Linuxios says, the optional boolean is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the C code in Ruby 2.3.0, you will see that `attr` and `attr_reader` are actually doing the same thing (except for the deprecated code path). They are essentially equivalent functions.

For me, the main differences are:

`attr` is a bit easier to write down as it's shorter. I like the way it feels in the context of functional/immutable programming too (in those contexts, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` are irrelevant and thus using `attr_reader` feels verbose and redundant).

`attr` with multiple instance variables makes it hard to document, except in very specific situations, e.g.

```
# The coordinates in WGS84.
attr :x, :y

# The location name.
attr :name

# The popularity of the location.
attr :popularity
```

It would be harder to document `:name` and `:popularity` independently if they were on the same line `attr :name, :popularity`.

Apart from that it boils down to personal preference. There is in practice no performance difference or any other difference.

Answer (score 1):

`attr` and `attr_accessor` are methods in Ruby that are used to define instance variables in classes.

`attr` creates a simple getter method that returns the value of an instance variable with the same name as the symbol passed as an argument. For example:

```rb
class MyClass
  attr :my_variable

  def initialize
    @my_variable = "Hello World"
  end
end

my_object = MyClass.new
puts my_object.my_variable # outputs "Hello World"
```

`attr_accessor` creates both ***getter*** and ***setter*** methods for an instance variable with the same name as the symbol passed as an argument. For example:

```rb
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_variable

  def initialize
    @my_variable = "Hello World"
  end
end

my_object = MyClass.new
puts my_object.my_variable # outputs "Hello World"
my_object.my_variable = "Goodbye World"
puts my_object.my_variable # outputs "Goodbye World"
```

In the example above, `my_object.my_variable` can be read and written. The `attr_accessor` method creates both getter and setter methods, allowing the value of the instance variable to be read and written.