# What is the difference between the following two?

Tags: ruby

First,

```
 attr :x, true
 attr :y, true
```

Second

```
attr_accessor :x, :y
```

What is the difference between those two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958061/attr-vs-attr-accessor

Comment: where you see `true` one.. any _Gem_ you are using ?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Nice link..

Comment: `attr == attr_reaer` they both create a reader method only. But if we add `attr :atribute, true` then it equals to `attr_accessor` (reader + writer)